# Using core data generated classes as model objects ...?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

Its more of a best practices sort of question. Here it goes...

I have automatically generated some classes for my entities in core data , now I want to use them as model objects to convert those models in JSON and send it over to the server. So my question is whether it is ok to use these classes or should I create separate classes and use a data mapper class to map these core data and model classes...

Which is a better approach and why...?

Thanks for your inputs...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use your `NSManagedObject` subclasses and add methods to those classes as you would any other NSObject class. This is perfectly acceptable (and would be better practice than to create separate object classes and using data mappers).

Comment: I would like to point out in addition to your answer that due to the fact that Xcode overwrites the auto generated subclass files should you generate them more than once, it is better to extend your NSManagedObject subclasses through categories in separate implementation file.

Comment: That is the point of a context, to keep track of all the objects. You should not try to do it yourself externally. If you are not happy with the changes you can always throw the context away without saving, or you could rollback to last saved state, or you could use undo manager to undo a whole group of changes. Context is there to help you, not hinder.

Comment: @svena you don't have to generate the classes from Xcode at all. I usually generate them once and then if I have to add a property to a model I just manually enter the property into the NSManagedObject subclass as well. This doesn't take any more time then it would take to re-generate the class.

Comment: Yes, that is true. But _if_ you decide to use auto generation, it is good to know.

Comment: So, If  I wanted to keep the info of the user as a strong property in my singleton class, it would be ok to make a strong variable of NSmanagedObject in my singleton class and use it throughout the app?

Answer (score 0):

Use [mogen](http://rentzsch.github.com/mogenerator/) to avoid the problem mentioned by @svena. It will automatically manage generation of core data models to prevent overriding your own code. Also I would suggest trying [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit) for server interactions. At least you can borrow their object serialization code because it does exactly what you want.